# 403 error Magento

Tags: .htaccess, magento

I added this line in my htaccess in a magento installation and now I have a 403 error. Any idea what could possible be wrong? Thanks a lot

```
    <IfModule mod_expires.c>

############################################
## Add default Expires header
## http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#expires

ExpiresActive On
ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 year"
```

Comment: Just to be sure -- you're closing with `</IfModule>`, correct?

Comment: Yeah I think this was the problem...